# PSTricks not working in TeXlive 2014

Tags: pstricks

I have TeXlive 2014 recently installed on a new machine. Everything seems to be working smoothly EXCEPT for PSTricks. I am testing with minimal code such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage{multido}  

\begin{document}

-- N   -- \rnode{2}{OP} -  C -- \ldots \rnode{1}{t} ---

\psset{linestyle=dashed,linearc=2pt,nodesepA=.1, nodesepB=.3} 
    \ncbar[angle=-90]{<-}{2}{1} 

\end{document}
```

This compiles cleanly on my old machine, running TeXlive 2008. On the new machine, I get the following error when compiling in TeXShop with TeX + DVI:

```
Error: /undefined in NodeScale
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   false   N@2   16   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1900   1   3   %oparray_pop   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1168/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:116/200(L)--   --dict:183/300(L)--   --dict:117/200(L)--   --dict:48/400(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 128730
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.5908-1406243855/mwe.pdf ()
```

I take it the issue with the creation of the PS file itself, since it can't be converted to PDF by Acrobat, either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This runs without problem on my machine (running TeX Live 2014) producing [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pWF33.png).

Comment: Yes, that's what I see on my older machine. Your comment suggests it's not the distribution (and of course it's not, the whole world would be screaming if PSTricks quit working!) but I'm not sure what else could be involved.

Comment: Are you running it using the compile sequence LaTeX > dvips (> ps2pdf)?

Comment: Yes, through dvips. That is the way that works on the old machine.

Comment: Your  files `pst-node.tex` and `pst-node.pro` are _not_ up-to-date. Put `\listfiles` as first line into your document and post the file list which is at the end of your log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an up-to-date TL 2014 you should get this file list:

```
*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pst-node.sty 2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pstricks.sty 2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex 2014/05/19 v2.54a `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty 2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex 2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
pst-fp.tex 2014/05/19 v2.54a `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro 2012/10/16 v. 1.15, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro 2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro 2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro 2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
xetex.def 2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)
pst-node.tex 2014/03/25 1.33 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
```

I used this example and run it with `xelatex`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

-- N   -- \rnode{2}{OP} -  C -- \ldots \rnode{1}{t} ---
\ncbar[linestyle=dashed,linearc=2pt,nodesepA=.1, nodesepB=.3,angle=-90]{<-}{2}{1} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Herbert, updating pst-node solved the problem. The version I had been using was dated 2000. I wonder why this didn't update with TeXlive 2014?!

Comment: No. TL 2014 had an up-to-date version. There must be something different in your distribution. However, it is working now and that#S fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only to put everything in a `pspicture` (compiles with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
-- N   -- \rnode{2}{OP} -  C -- \ldots \rnode{1}{t} ---
\psset{linestyle=dashed,linearc=2pt,nodesepA=.1, nodesepB=.3}
    \ncbar[angle=-90]{<-}{2}{1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This compiled in pdftex (after I noticed that you'd added [pdf] to the document class) but did not print the figure correctly. It only printed the long dash, N, longdash. Error "Non-PDF special ignored!" 4x.

Comment: What are you supposed to obtain? Do you mean you didn't obtain the same figure as in my answer? I also can compile via LaTeX->dvi->ps and get exactly the same result. No error message.

Comment: May be try updating GhostScript (last version is 9.14).

Comment: the environment `pspicture` is _not_ needed.

Comment: @Herbert: There's an error message with the `pdf` option if I don't use a pspicture environment. It seems to be a problem with auto-pst-pdf, as the filename-autopp-log, after a torrent of insults, ends with `(job aborted, no legal \end found).

Comment: what you are looking for is the environment `postscript` and not `pspciture` which by default saves a square of 10cm x 10cm which is often not what someones wants. The `postscript` environment does nothing else than telling `pst-pdf` to handle it separately and insert it as an image.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip. Is it documented somewhere?